# Debezium 1.5: Elasticsearch sink connector not adding anything to cluster

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, debezium

I recently updated my Debezium images from 1.4 to 1.5.
However now when I insert my connectors it seems like the sink conenctor just kind of 'dies' without giving any output at all..

Everything runs fine on 1.4 but I need to upgrade to 1.5 due to some new features that are necessary for my project.

below is my DockerFile for the debezium connect image:

```
FROM debezium/connect:1.5
ENV KAFKA_CONNECT_JDBC_DIR=$KAFKA_CONNECT_PLUGINS_DIR/kafka-connect-jdbc \
KAFKA_CONNECT_ES_DIR=$KAFKA_CONNECT_PLUGINS_DIR/kafka-connect-elasticsearch

ARG POSTGRES_VERSION=42.2.20
ARG KAFKA_JDBC_VERSION=10.0.0
ARG KAFKA_ELASTICSEARCH_VERSION=10.0.0  

# Deploy PostgreSQL JDBC Driver
RUN cd /kafka/libs && curl -sO https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download/postgresql-$POSTGRES_VERSION.jar

# Deploy Kafka Connect JDBC
RUN mkdir $KAFKA_CONNECT_JDBC_DIR && cd $KAFKA_CONNECT_JDBC_DIR &&\
    curl -sO https://packages.confluent.io/maven/io/confluent/kafka-connect-jdbc/$KAFKA_JDBC_VERSION/kafka-connect-jdbc-$KAFKA_JDBC_VERSION.jar


# Deploy Confluent Elasticsearch sink connector
RUN mkdir $KAFKA_CONNECT_ES_DIR && cd $KAFKA_CONNECT_ES_DIR &&\
        curl -sO https://packages.confluent.io/maven/io/confluent/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/$KAFKA_ELASTICSEARCH_VERSION/kafka-connect-elasticsearch-$KAFKA_ELASTICSEARCH_VERSION.jar && \
        curl -sO https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/searchbox/jest/6.3.1/jest-6.3.1.jar && \
        curl -sO https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore-nio/4.4.4/httpcore-nio-4.4.4.jar && \
        curl -sO https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.1/httpclient-4.5.1.jar && \
        curl -sO https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpasyncclient/4.1.1/httpasyncclient-4.1.1.jar && \
        curl -sO https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.4/httpcore-4.4.4.jar && \
        curl -sO https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2/commons-logging-1.2.jar && \
        curl -sO https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.9/commons-codec-1.9.jar && \
        curl -sO https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.4/httpcore-4.4.4.jar && \
        curl -sO https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/searchbox/jest-common/6.3.1/jest-common-6.3.1.jar && \
        curl -sO https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.8.6/gson-2.8.6.jar  && \
        curl -sO https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/20.0/guava-20.0.jar
```

My Elasticsearch sink connector:

```
{
  "name": "es-sink-connector",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "topics": "report",
    "connection.url": "http://elasticsearch:9200",
    "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState",
    "transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones": "false",
    "transforms.unwrap.drop.deletes": "false",  
    "key.ignore": "false",
    "type.name": "_doc",
    "behavior.on.null.values": "delete",
    "transforms": "ExtractKey",
    "transforms.ExtractKey.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key",
    "transforms.ExtractKey.field": "id"
  }
}
```

And lastly, the docker-compose configurations for my debeium-connect

```
  connect:
    build: ./debezium-jdbc-es
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
      - "5005:5005" 
    depends_on:
      - kafka
      - elasticsearch
    environment:
      - BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=kafka:9092
      - GROUP_ID=1
      - CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_configs
      - OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_offsets
      - STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_source_connect_statuses
      - host.docker.internal= host.docker.internal
```

Any idea as to how to fix it/ why it might not be working is appreciated!

Thank you!

---

UPDATE:

So after looking a bit more into it, it seems to be due to my Postgres connector not finding my table and not my Elasticsearch sink connector.

Debezium 1.4:

```
Snapshot step 3 - Locking captured tables [repo.report]   [io.debezium.relational.RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource]
```

Debezium 1.5:

```
Snapshot step 3 - Locking captured tables []   [io.debezium.relational.RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource]
```

This is my Postgres connector:

```
{
  "name": "reporting-connector",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "database.hostname": "host.docker.internal",
    "database.port": "5432",
    "database.user": "debezium_user",
    "database.password": "postgres",
    "database.server.id": "184054",
    "database.dbname": "reportdatabase",
    "database.server.name": "reporting",
    "plugin.name": "pgoutput",
    "database.include.list": "reportdatabase",
    "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kafka:9092",
    "database.history.kafka.topic": "reporting",
    "schema.include.list":"repo",
    "table.include.list":"repo.report",
    "transforms": "route",
    "transforms.route.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter",
    "transforms.route.regex": "([^.]+)\\.([^.]+)\\.([^.]+)",
    "transforms.route.replacement": "$3"
  }
}
```

Comment: When you hit the `/status` endpoint of the connector, you get what?

Comment: @OneCricketeer It says that the connector is running but it is not doing anything once the source connector has gotten the changes.

{"name":"es-sink-connector","connector":{"state":"RUNNING","worker_id":"172.20.0.5:8083"},"tasks":[{"id":0,"state":"RUNNING","worker_id":"172.20.0.5:8083"}],"type":"sink"}

Comment: Thanks. And if you consume the reports topic, it's actively getting data produced to it? And the sink connector consumer group has a lag higher than zero?

Comment: @OneCricketeer Hello again, so I looked a bit closer to the logs and it seems to be due to my Postgres source connector not being able to find my table anymore? I have updated the question with the Postgres source connector as well as the outputs from debezium 1.4 and 1.5

Comment: I've not used Debezium, really, but I would advise running the Postgres database in its own container rather than having `host.docker.internal` as your connection string, if possible. Other than that, maybe refer the Debezium changelog to see what has changed